# Set environment variable for unity application launcher

Tags: linux, ubuntu, launcher

I've created a `.desktop` file to launch our application. Our application requires, that a certain environment variable is configured correctly. Where can I configure this environment variable on a per-user base (the usual candidates I know, like `~/.bashrc` and `~/.profile` don't work).

Maybe there is a work-around, so I can configure it in the `Exec=` line of the `.desktop` file before launching the application?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In the desktop file itself, you can execute the program through `env`:

```
Exec=/usr/bin/env VAR=value /usr/bin/yourprogram
```

Alternatively, use a wrapper script (e.g. `/usr/bin/yourprogram.env`):

```
#!/bin/sh
VAR=value
export VAR
exec /usr/bin/yourprogram.real "$@"
```

However, both are poor solutions, since Unity will not be able to correctly track the program if it is started through a wrapper.

It would be much better to get `~/.profile` working – make sure you're using the correct syntax and all that:

```
export VAR=value
```

or

```
VAR=value
export VAR
```

Also remember that `~/.profile` is only read *when you log in*, so you must log out after changing it.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, your suggestion to use `env VAR=value /my/app` does not work; the environment variable `VAR` is not set to `value` when `/my/app` launches (I've tried by editing the `desktop` file in `~/.gnome/apps`). Creating a wrapper script is no option for me, because this should work for our application distributed to end-users and I don't know where the end-user would want the wrapper script to be located (creating the launcher must not require admin rights).

Comment: *(Huh? I didn't know `~/.gnome/apps` was still in use; it's been called `~/.local/share/applications` for the past few years.)* @Mike, if it's your own application, why cannot it be fixed to automatically determine the proper environment variable? (Also, can I ask *which* variable specifically are you setting?)

Comment: I'm trying to set a variable defining the location of the Java runtime environment for our application.

Comment: perhaps use some of the standard locations http://standards.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html

Comment: I've installed the `.desktop` file using `xdg-desktop-menu install <my-desktop-file>`. It looks like it copied it to two locations and I always was editing the wrong one...

Comment: In what way will Unity be unable to track the program?